# How to get product ids from $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()

Tags: event-observer

When using

```
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($OrderNo);
```

I can access product ids by

```
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item)
{
    if ($item->getParentItemId() != NULL) continue;

    echo $item->getProductId();
}
```

But when I access the order via an event observer this method fails.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

How do I get product ids in this case?

Comment: which event u r using ?

Comment: I am using sales_order_save_after

Comment: try this $ProdustIds=array();
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
{
    $ProdustIds[]= $item->getProductId();
}

Comment: Try to use events `sales_order_payment_place_end` or `sales_order_save_commit_after` or `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your observer gives you the order object you can get the product ids by using the process below:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

if( $order->getId() ) {
    $ProductIds = array();
    foreach( $order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item ) {
        $ProductIds[] = $item->getProductId();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi here is my xml file :

```
<global>
   <config>
     <events>
      <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <order_backendordermgt>
            <class>order_backendordermgt/observer</class>
            <method>updateOrderType</method>
            </order_backendordermgt>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

here is my observer :

```
class Order_Backendordermgt_Model_Observer {    
    public function updateOrderType(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $increment_id = $order->getincrement_id();
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach($items as $item){
        echo $item->getName();
        // custom code to update order or any thing
        }
        $orders->save();
    }
}
```

i think this can help you.